# Всплывающий div в зависимости от значения переменной в php

Tags: jquery, php, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток господа

Есть скрипт всплывающего дива:

```
// тут подключается jquery
<script type="text/javascript">
var popupStatus = 0;

function loadPopup(){
    if(popupStatus==0){
        $("#backgroundPopup").css({
            "opacity": "0.5"
        });
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeIn("slow");
        $("#popupContact").fadeIn("slow");
        popupStatus = 1;
    }
}

function disablePopup(){
    if(popupStatus==1){
        $("#backgroundPopup").fadeOut("slow");
        $("#popupContact").fadeOut("slow");
        popupStatus = 0;
    }
}

function centerPopup(){
    var windowWidth = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    var windowHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var popupHeight = $("#popupContact").height();
    var popupWidth = $("#popupContact").width();
    $("#popupContact").css({
        "position": "absolute",
        "top": windowHeight/2-popupHeight/2,
        "left": windowWidth/2-popupWidth/2
    });
    $("#backgroundPopup").css({
        "height": windowHeight
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        centerPopup();
        loadPopup();
    });
    $("#popupContactClose").click(function(){
        disablePopup();
    });
    $("#backgroundPopup").click(function(){
        disablePopup();
    });
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
            disablePopup();
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

В отличии от многих примеров из инета, у меня он работает, по крайней мере в таком виде. Для использования его делается кнопка:

```
<center>
<div id="button"><input type="submit" value="кнопка"></div>
</center>
<div id="popupContact">
<a id="popupContactClose">x</a>
тут мы пишем что хотим
</div>
<div id="backgroundPopup"></div>
```

Допустим у меня в php коде есть переменная $okno. Как убрать кнопку (которую нужно нажимать, что бы увидеть div), и в место этого показывать div автоматически, если переменная $okno = yes ?

т.е. допустим загружается страница, в php коде $okno = "yes"; - окошко всплывает автоматически. если $okno != "yes"; - ничего не происходит.

p.s. конечно не беда сделать так, что бы окно не всплывало при $okno != "yes"; в основном хочу просто узнать как избавиться от кнопки, и сделать автоматическую активацию всплывающего окна

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вам надо чтобы это было именно в js файле не формируемым php - передавайте при его загрузке get параметры и на них ориентируйтесь (`src="myjs.js?showdiv=<?=$okno?>"`)

либо перенесите блок **.ready** в файл генерируемый php и там уже средствами php или вызывайте или нет нужную функцию:

```
<?php if($okno=="lala") { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
centerPopup();
loadPopup();
});
</script>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: ок, разобрался. спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />
    <title>Окно</title>
</head>

<body>

<!--Получаем полный путь-->
<script type="text/javascript">
    var url = location.href; 
    document.write(url);
</script>

<!--Жмякаем по кнопке чтобы отправить get запрос-->
<input name="Показать окно" type="button" value="okno" onclick="win()"/>

<!--Проверяем отправился ли get запрос-->
<script type="text/javascript">
function win(){
    window.location = url + "?okno=yes";
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Ну а дальше уже добавляйте условия чего вы хотели бы сделать при наличии get. В код можно встроить php-скрипт с условием, а можно только JS обойтись. Спрашивайте если еще возникнут вопросы по работе данной конструкции.

Comment: эмм.. код я себе возьму на вооружение, но тут кнопка (я в вопросе указал, что от кнопки как раз хочу избавиться) . пример хорош конечно, но то что в первом посте это укороченная версия моего кода, в котором есть много других нюансов.

Comment: $okno - это не get переменная, а php переменная. И как тут окно автоматически появляется?

Comment: @Чад, не понял вашего несогласия и вопроса! Значение символа $ в PHP мне известно, но где вы у меня увидели вообще использование PHP, и я не говорил про автоматическое появление окна, я же ниже пояснил свою конструкцию сказав о том, что цитирую: "В код можно встроить php-скрипт с условием, а можно только JS обойтись.". Я и не собирался давать готового решения, здесь мы рассматриваем лишь методы решения.

Comment: @archi_sova, я отвечал когда вы только код выложили. Без пояснения. Вопрос был в том "зачем собаке хвост" :-) Смысл такой передачи get параметра? Если можно пхп скриптом сконфигурировать? Т.е. если следовать этой логике то мы на пхп проверяем переменную $okno, потом формируем html, который делает редирект с get переменной. А в чём соль, и как это относится к вопросу?

Comment: @Чад, я не понимаю о какой собаке и о каком хвосте вы мне рассказываете и что вы мне хотите доказать или объяснить, у вас свой вариант у меня свой, в чем вопрос!?