# Конфликт двух скриптов. JS и AJAX

Tags: jquery, скрипт, ajax, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток господа.

Есть 2 работающих скрипта (работают по отдельности) :

[первый](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/149753/javascript-%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BB%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%B9-div-%D0%B2-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%B2-php)

```
// добавлено после 2й функции
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
centerPopup();
loadPopup();
});
</script>
```

второй

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a").click(function() {
            var id = $(this).attr('id');
            $.ajax({
                url: "page.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {id: id},
                success: function(text) {
                    $("#text").html(text);
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Возникла проблема, вместе - все хорошо, до тех пор пока первым скриптом я не нажимаю кнопку, которая во всплывающем окне

```
// сама кнопка выглядит так
<a id="popupContactClose">x</a>

// нажимая на нее происходит то, что описано в скрипте
$("#popupContactClose").click(function(){
    disablePopup();
});
// и после этого активируется AJAX
```

Подскажите, как переписать код, что бы AJAX не реагировал?

p.s. пока решил проблему так, но это так себе решение:

```
// назначил переход по ссылке, на текущую страницу
$("#popupContactClose").click(function(){
    location="page.php?id=<? echo $id; ?>";
});
```

p.p.s.

```
// если нажать esc, или нажать не на всплывающее окно (рядом, чтоб окно погасло) - AJAX не срабатывает, хотя там прописаны аналогичные команды
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#button").click(function(){
        centerPopup();
        loadPopup();
    });
    $("#popupContactClose").click(function(){
        disablePopup();
    });
    $("#backgroundPopup").click(function(){
        disablePopup();
    });
    $(document).keypress(function(e){
        if(e.keyCode==27 && popupStatus==1){
            disablePopup();
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 $("a").click(function() {
```

Функция выполнится при нажатии на любую ссылку. Так что работает все так, как и написано. Раз надо, чтобы при клике на `a#popupContactClose` действие не выполнялось, достаточно прописать это в условие. Например,

```
   $("a").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        if(id != 'popupContactClose') {
           $.ajax({
            url: "page.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {id: id},
            success: function(text) {
                $("#text").html(text);
            }
           });
         }
    });
```

Или избавьтесь от тега "a". Кому нужен этот тег без значения "href"? Используйте "div", "span"... Неужели мало тегов?

Comment: да. так все и оказалось. спасибо

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#popupContactClose").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    disablePopup();
});
```

Comment: ох. рад бы и принять. но данная кнопка просто не нажимается теперь

Comment: Какая кнопка? Закрытия попапа?

Comment: <a id="popupContactClose">x</a>
 - она не пропала. просто при нажатии на нее ничего не происходит. 40 минут тестировал, думал у меня что то не так.

Comment: Очень странно..  Выложи весь код (HTML и JS) на jsfiddle.net и кинь сюда ссылку - посмотрю

Comment: ответ Равнодушный'ого оказался правильным, думаю вопрос решен, по крайней мере в том виде как я его задал